# Cannot install python-minimal on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, 17.10

I have been trying to install python-minimal on Ubuntu 17.10 but getting this error.

```
sudo apt-get install python-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib python python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,695 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,951 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-minimal.
(Reading database ... 303638 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.14-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../python-minimal_2.7.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.14-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.14-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython-stdlib_2.7.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu2) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried install using .deb file but still no luck.

Kindly help me out.

Update 1 

 Output of  `sudo apt -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.14-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.10.20170810-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Update 2

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python-minimal:amd64
```

Comment: Hello, please run the following command and then please post the output: `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @mchid posted, please check

Comment: Okay, please try `sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal` and then please post the output, thanks!

Comment: @mchid check please

Answer (score 0):

Okay, please run the following commands to hopefully fix the issue and please post any errors, thanks:

```
sudo apt update
mkdir PYTHON; cd PYTHON 
apt-get download python-minimal
sudo dpkg -i python*deb
```

Comment: Same and nothing changes!  Keep getting the same error!

Comment: @SauravKumar Have you tried running `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update` before running the commands? If not, then first run those commands and then delete the downloaded deb file and try to run `apt-get download python-minimal` and then run the `sudo dpkg -i py*deb` command.

Comment: Yes I tried everything. Nothing worked. Though I was able to fix this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026780/error-upgrading-ubuntu-16-04-lts-python-minimal-package-error